# Java mongodb - find then average

Tags: java, mongodb

Okey, let's start. Imagine that we have the next mongo collection:

```
{
 "city": "TWENTYNINE PALMS", 
 "loc": [-116.06041, 34.237969], 
 "pop":   11412, 
 "state": "CA", 
 "_id": "92278"
}

{
"city": "NEW CUYAMA", 
"loc": [-74.823806, 34.996709], 
"pop": 80, 
"state": "CA", 
"_id": "93254"
}

{
"city": "WATERBURY", 
"loc": [-72.996268, 41.550328], 
"pop": 25128, 
"state": "CT", 
"_id": "06705"
}
```

**Notice that loc array is [latitude,longitude]**

I would like to obtain using java mongo driver the "pop" average of the cities that have the altitude beetwen -75,-70.

So, using SQL I know that the query is:

```
SELECT avg(pop)
WHERE loc.altitude > -75 AND lloc.altitude < -70
```

I am very noob in mongodb, this is my current code:

```
    BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("loc.0", new BasicDBObject("$gte",
            -75).append("$lte", -70));

    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(doc);
```

The previous code returns me all the documents that altitude are beetwen (-75,-70), **but I do not know how to obtain the average,using mongo driver, I know that I can iterate over results using java.**.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** with following aggregation pipeline (Mongo shell implementation):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "loc.0": { "$gte": -75 },
            "loc.1": { "$lte": 70 }
        }        
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "average": {
                "$avg": "$pop"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

With the example above, this outputs to console:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "average" : 12604
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

With Java, this can be implemented as follows:

```
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject();
match.put("loc.0", new BasicDBObject("$gte", -75));
match.put("loc.1", new BasicDBObject("$lte", 70));

DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", 0);
groupFields.put("average", new BasicDBObject( "$avg", "$pop"));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate( match, group );
```